# Word-wrap is not working

Tags: html

I want to display 50 characters on a cell. The problem is the width of the cell is 50px, How can i display the string in two lines(the string is without space) on that cell.

Comment: word-wrap is css3, so make sure your browser is actually hip enough to understand css3

Comment: Wait, 50 characters in a 50 pixel wide td? And you want it in two lines? That would give you 2 pixels per character, is that enough?

Comment: @NiftyDude IE was actually that hip long before the other browsers were. But you're right, it depends on the browser of course.

Comment: @MrLister Yes Yes :D I used to lurve IE, don't get me wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from the impossibility of the task as presented (see Mr Lister’s comment), you can specify allowed line break points with the [`<wbr>` tag](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/nobr.html#wbr).